# How to create two webparts within a single spfx solution?

Tags: spfx

My ultimate aim is create an spfx project that allows me to add two web parts to an SPO page. The two webparts will be connected to a different custom list each. Webpart (A) will have a button next to an item, if the user clicks that button then it will filter Webpart (B) based on what the ID of the item in Webpart (A).
I've already created an spfx project. It currently has one `.ts` file which has the 'entry point' to the project.
This allows me to add that webpart to an SPO page. As mentioned above I want to be able to create two different webparts to an SPO page.
The question: Would I create two 'entry point' `.ts` files? Or is this not necessary?
If it's not necessary, how do I make it so?

Is there any sample code apart from this - 
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-events-dynamicdata

For your information here is some of the entry point code I'm referring to:

```
...
export default class ConnectedWebpartsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IConnectedWebpartsWebPartProps> {
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      // other init code may be present
      pnpSetup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });
    });
  }
...
```

Tom

Answer (score 0):

It's simple - just use Yeoman and run another yo @microsoft/sharepoint within the folder of your existing project.
Now to try to get those 2 webparts connected....that's the tricky bit.